# How test Model Logic class with Unit Test in asp.net mvc4 without run webserver?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I have logic class: MyUtil.cs inside Models folder for asp.net mvc4 app.

Auto generated unit tests for MyUtils.cs create unit test that working with webserver (use attr:[HostType("ASP.NET")][UrlToTest("http://localhost:1139/") etc..]).

What should I change for make this unit test run without server?

Thanks,

Yosef

Answer (score 1):

The best and simplest solution would be to **not use the auto-generator** for unit tests but write the tests yourself. There are many articles and tutorials out there and this one can be a good place to start:

- **[Introduction to Test-Driven Development with ASP.NET MVC](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2009/07/22/introduction-to-test-driven-development-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx)**

Comment: Then I'd recommend choosing a testing framework and writing the required tests. Still: Don't use the test generator. If you don't know how unit tests work then get yourself up to speed. The article I mentioned in my answer is a good start.